# How do I perform clearRect() in canvas after clip()?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I need to perform clearRect() after performing clip() in canvas. Unfortunately, It does not working for me.

If I exclude clip() means, clearRect() is working fine me.

```
<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 150);
ctx.clip();  //after removing clip() clearRect() working
ctx.clearRect(20, 20, 100, 50);
</script>
```

I need to perform clearRect() after performing clip(). Is this possible?

Please find the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/edwp7xz5/)

```js
public canvasClip(options: BaseAttibutes): void {
        this.ctx.save();
        this.ctx.rect(options.x, options.y, options.width, options.height);
        this.ctx.clip();
    }


  public clearRect(rect: Rect): void {
        this.ctx.restore();
        this.ctx.clearRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
    };
```

If I called clearRect() after calling canvasClip(), it did not worked for me.

thanks in advance,
Kesavan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way `clip()` works is that it takes the current sub-path declaration and everything that should not be in its filled area will be discarded from the drawing zone. That is, if you draw again something outside of this area, then it won't appear on the context.

I guess your confusion comes from [`fillRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect) though. This method is a bit special in that it creates a **temporary** rectangular sub-path that is only used for this method (`strokeRect` does the same).

Here is a visual example of what this means:

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// declare a sub-path 
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(50,50,30,0,Math.PI*2); // circle

// this will discard our circle
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect(120, 50, 30, 30);

// wait a bit to show it has been discarded
setTimeout(() => {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
  ctx.fill(); // this draws only the circle,
  // the internal rect() in fillRect() has disappeared,
  // otherwise it would be blue now
}, 1000);
```

```css
canvas {border: 1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500"></canvas>
```

So you actually didn't declare any Sub-Path on your context before calling `clip()`, and the new drawing area (unclipped) is a 0x0px path (i.e it doesn't exists).  Every drawing operation (and `clearRect` is one) will then have no effect.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// what OP did is equivalent to
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.clip(); // clip a non-existent sub-path

// you can try to draw, it won't work
ctx.arc(50,50,30,0,Math.PI*2);
ctx.fill();
ctx.fillRect(120, 50, 30, 30);
```

```css
canvas {border: 1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500"></canvas>
```

<sub>The only method that would still have an effect would be `putImageData`.</sub>

And since you can only *remove* drawing areas, by clipping this non-area, you actually locked your context in this state.*
So before using `clip()`, always call `ctx.save()` in order to be able to reset the clipping area afterward.
*<sub><sup>Well it could still be unlocked by setting the canvas width or height, but that's bad m'kayy?</sup></sub>

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// so we can reset our clipping area
ctx.save();

ctx.fillStyle = "red";
// use `rect()` which does add to the current sub-path
ctx.rect(0, 0, 300, 150);
ctx.fill();
ctx.clip();

ctx.clearRect(20, 20, 100, 50); // now we can clear

ctx.restore(); // remove the clipping area
ctx.fillRect(320, 0, 20, 20); // now we can draw anywhere
```

```css
canvas {border: 1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500"></canvas>
```

But note that instead of clipping, most of the time, you're better using [compositing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) which results in cleaner antialising, and often in better performances. But since I don't know why you wanted to use clip, I can't really show you the equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have tried this in my code. It does not work for me. Please find the below code snippet in the question. Please find that and give me suggetion for that.

Comment: Can you set up a **live** example? For instance on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net). There must be something wrong in your implementation.

Comment: @KesavanSubramaniam for one, you never fill() after you did `rect()`, then `restore()` only if you want to discard your previously set `clipped` area, then double check the `option` you receive.

Comment: Please find the [image](https://imgur.com/a/xDzAahl). I have drawn two rectangles A and B. I have applied clip() to B. If I perform clearRect() with the A's dimensions. Only B is cleared. But I need to clear entire A. So only I have applied restore() before clearRect().

Comment: Ok and what doesn't work? Can you set up a **live and minimal** example please?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your suggestions are working fine for me.